# SQL Server Report Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm create a SQL Server Report using Business Intelligence tool (visual studio shell 2005) for SQL Server 2008.

I'm calling a stored procedure with 2 parameters. I've tried - Report-> Report Parameter, Added two parameters name them Days and Count.

In the Data panel "command type:text"

> exec dbo.DataReport @Days, @Count

error: Must delcare the scalar variable "@Days"

Does anyone know how do get this too work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the command type to Stored Procedure, i'm sure its worked for me in the past

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried this. dbo.DataReport @Days, @Count gives an error. I've then change it dbo.DataReport does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the command type to Stored Procedure like was suggested didn't work, try opening the Dataset dialog box and going to "Parameters" tab.  Make sure that both parameters ("@Days" and "@Count") are in the list and that each one has a value.